# Can the subject of an infinitive be omitted in passive voice?

Tags: infinitives

> The technicians were fired to reduce costs.

I have a doubt about whether this sentence is grammatically correct or not and whether I must add "for a noun" so as to make it clear what was to reduce costs as in "The technicians were fired for the company to reduce costs".

To sum up, is it grammatically correct to omit "for the company"? and even if it's grammatically incorrect, do native speakers tend to violate the rule that we must make it explicit what is the subject that "to reduce costs" modifies?

Comment: I'm struggling to see why you think this is a grammatically incorrect sentence. "Costs" here is a noun. "Firing the technicians will reduce costs" is correct as well, the passive voice has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Can you give an example sentence with this omission?

Comment: @scatter Like.. can't I change this sentence "I put up the old car for sale to buy a new one" as "The old car was put up for sale to buy a new one" ?

Comment: @scatter That is because if I omit that, native speakers would think of "to reduce costs" as modifying "the technicians". Wouldn't they think this way if I omit "for the company"?

Comment: @Floret: This native speaker would not think of "to reduce costs" as modifying "the technicians", because this native speaker was familiar with a purpose clause such as "to reduce costs" before he knew what a clause was.

Comment: This example is entirely grammatical and idiomatic. Adding "for the company" would make it sound awkward, not better. :)

Comment: The sentence is grammatical, but it's a little confusing. It would be clearer if written as *the technicians were fired **in order** to reduce costs.* (Compare the original with *the technicians were **excited** to reduce costs.*) We can understand what's meant in context, but the syntax can be improved so that it's more explicit.

Comment: @JasonBassford What does **"the technicians were excited to reduce costs"** mean? I think it would mean **(1)"As soon as costs were reduced, the technicians were excited"** or **(2)"the technicians want to reduce costs"**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends entirely on the context.  For example, you could write

> The technicians were fired to reduce **the company's** costs.

but

1. "The company" is not really the *subject* of the infinitive.  The possessive is an adjective modifying "costs"
2. The passive tense already implies the subject is *whoever employs the technicians*.  It's not necessary to explicitly repeat this to relate it to costs.
3. It's fairly obvious that it's the employers who are going to save money from this action, not the technicians.

You would have to add specifics if it is not clear what the infinitive clause modifies.  For example:

> The technicians were promoted **to improve productivity**.

Although this sentence is grammatical, it's not clear whose productivity is improved.  The technicians?  The company overall?  The executives who make these kind of decisions?  Better to be clear:

> The technicians were promoted to improve **company** productivity.

Answer (score 2):

**The technicians were fired to reduce costs**

is perfectly acceptable. "to reduce costs" is the reason why they were fired.